# How to demonstrate lack of stability with advection equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration, stability

I am trying to that using a coarse grid with an explicit method for, say, the advection equation leads to an unstable solution. The trouble is *Mathematica* avoids unstable solutions with good `Method`s or I am unable to set a coarse spatial grid or temporal grid spacing.

**My code is as follows:**

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
    0.5 D[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x],  
   u[t, -Pi] == u[t, Pi] == 0 , u[0, x] == Sin[x]}, 
  u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, MaxStepFraction -> 1/10]
```

**And a plot of sol is:**

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All
```

[image]

Should I not be using `MaxStepFraction` to demonstrate instability? What is the most coarse explicit `Method` I could use? I have tried `Method->{"ExplicitEuler"}` but this was good enough to resolve instabilities and I found a stable solution without kinks at larger times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forcing large enough constant step size (in time) for `NDSolve` method lead to instabilitity.

```
 sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 0.5 D[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x], 
   u[t, -Pi] == u[t, Pi] == 0, u[0, x] == Sin[x]}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -Pi, Pi},
     Method -> {"FixedStep", "Method" -> "ExplicitEuler", "StepSize" -> 1/10}];

Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Max step fraction you used `"StartingStepSize" -> 1/10` gives maximal step size of order $1/20$ for this particular integration time interval, which is small enough and gives stable evolution for explicit Euler algorithm. Of course stability depends on the ratio of spatial and temporal grid spacings. For this set of options *Mathematica* sets (and adapts) spatial grid resolution automatically. To force specific spatial grid, with discrete differentiation method, use the `"MethodOfLines"` option

```
 sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 0.5 D[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x], 
   u[t, -Pi] == u[t, Pi] == 0, u[0, x] == Sin[x]}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -Pi, Pi},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    Method -> {"FixedStep", "Method" -> "ExplicitEuler", "StepSize" -> 1/4},
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 16,
      "MaxPoints" -> 16, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}
  ]
```

With the same values of `"MinPoints"` and `"MaxPoints"` we force constant grid over the evolution. Manipulating this and the time step size you can demonstrate instability of the used method. For more on numerical methods for PDEs have a look at the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html).

Comment: Thank you. So is it difficult to back-out a "CFL" number out of this example when one uses mathematica since mma always "sets/adapts spatial grid resolution"?

Comment: @drN Yes of course, see the edit to my question.

Comment: Why when I increase the MaxPoints while holding MinPoints constant, does the error increase? I would assume the reverse should happen...

Comment: @drN Yes it should, but it also depends on the steps size you set...